Does Grafana support the PromQL modifier @?
I'm trying to visualize a Prometheus query in Grafana, but I'm facing an issue. The query:
mymetric{mylabel="value"} @ end()
works perfectly in Prometheus and returns a valid graph. However, when I paste this query into a Grafana Time Series panel, I don't see any graph or error message.
My question is:
Does Grafana support the @ modifier in Prometheus queries? If not, what alternatives can I use to achieve similar functionality?
Additional Information:

Grafana Version: 9.5.20
Prometheus Version: 2.50.1


Yes, it does. Check maybe you've set type of query to instant?

The query type is set to range.

IDK, play Grafana works. Check your options. Or maybe something version specific, but I very much doubt that.

Grafana options on my side are exactly the same as in your screenshot. Grafana Play is currently on version 11.x. My Grafana is two major versions behind. So probably something version related.
